# How to properly use Automapper in this situation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Good afternoon.
My question is, I have 2 Edit methods in my controller - get and post.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id)
        {
            var article = await _articleService.GetArticleAsync(id);
            var resultModel = _mapper.Map<ArticleDetailViewModel>(article);


            return View(resultModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ArticleDetailViewModel model)
        {
            await _articleService.UpdateArticle(_mapper.Map<ArticleDTO>(model));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Article");
        }
```

The Guid id of the Article comes into the Edit get method.  With this id, I find the entire ArticleDTO object and use the automapper to turn it into an ArticleDetailViewModel.  Next, I pass this model to the View.  In the Index post method, changes to the Article are edited and saved using the UpdateArticle(ArticleDTO) method.  In this method, I have to manually collect one entity from 2 entities and save it.

```
        public async Task UpdateArticle(ArticleDTO model)
        {
            var entity = await _unitOfWork.Articles.GetByIdAsync(model.Id);

            var articleResult = new Article()
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                Title = model.Title,
                Description = model.Description,
                Body = model.Body,
                CreationDate = model.CreationDate,
                PositivityGrade = entity.PositivityGrade,
                Comments = entity.Comments,
                Source = entity.Source,
                SourceId = entity.SourceId
            };

            _unitOfWork.Articles.Update(articleResult);
            await _unitOfWork.Comit();
        }
```

Please tell me how to avoid this, and use Automapper so as not to do it manually.  Or maybe there is some other way.

Comment: instead of having a variable articleResult why not just update the appropriate properties of entity variable and pass that to Update() method.  You could setup AutoMapper to do that or do it manually.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger unfortunately that's where the problem lies. In the controller, I get the ArticleDetailViewModel model with the Id, Title, Description, Body, CreationDate fields in the Edit post method. The rest of the fields are null or default. Therefore, I have to search for the original object in the UpdateArticle (ArticleDTO) method and manually match some of the fields that I do not change in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
public async Task UpdateArticle(ArticleDTO model)
{
    var entity = await _unitOfWork.Articles.GetByIdAsync(model.Id);
    
    var articleResult = _mapper.Map(model, entity)

    _unitOfWork.Articles.Update(articleResult);
    await _unitOfWork.Comit();
}
```